# How To Measure PBKDF2 SHA256 Hash Computation Time

Tags: encryption, hash, google-cloud-functions, pbkdf2

I need to measure how long it takes to compute my hash with x number of iterations. Here is code:

```
 function hashPromise(secretPhrase, keylen) {
 let hashedKey
 var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    crypto.pbkdf2(secretPhrase, 'salt', keylen, 256, 
    'sha256', (err, key) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            reject(err);
        } else {
            hashedKey = key.toString('hex')
            let time = new Date().getTime()
            console.log('keylen: ' + keylen)
            console.log('TIMESTAMP Hash Finished: ' + time)
            console.log('hashedKey: ' + hashedKey)
            resolve( hashedSSN )
        }
      })
  })

return promise;
}
```

I am looping through this function with promise.all a couple hundred times, passing in a new secretPhrase each time.

I am using a Firebase Functions http request to trigger this functions. Here are my logs when keylen is 1000:

[image]

And here are my logs if keylen is 500000

[image]

Would computation time simply be the difference between each 'TIMESTAMP Hash Finished'? Or would it be the time it took the entire function to finish (at top of logs)?

Ie- Computation time using a 500000 keylen is 1526473894031 - 1526473893718 = 313ms ?

Comment: FWIW: You have keylen hard-coded as 256 and the variable named keylen is actually iterations.

Comment: Wow, good catch. Thanks. Any idea on computation time?